# Lightbox by Lokesh Dhakar disableScrolling jumps to top of the page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, lightbox2

As the title says, I have this problem. The option to disable scrolling simply applies

> html.lb-disable-scrolling{overflow:hidden;position:fixed;height:100vh;width:100vw;}

To the html. Upon changing to set it to body instead of html and removing position it works as intended. (had to change target in js also from html to body)

> body.lb-disable-scrolling{overflow:hidden;height:100vh;width:100vw}

But I wonder if  there is a better solution?

EDIT: It seems that his solution also does not work on phone device.

Answer (score 1):

Just Add below line to your lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js  file.

```
lightbox.option({ disableScrolling: true });
```

go to [example](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/), open the console, and enter the above line.

After Enter Close Model and Open Image Again.It Will definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior was a bug in the Lightbox2 script. You can see a report of it here in the official repo: https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/620

It was fixed in v2.11.0 that was released April 21, 2019. Upgrading should resolve your issue.
https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/releases/tag/v2.11.0